Any way to get a reflection of struct method pointer having interface{} pointer to it as function argument?
Can not understand if it even possible in Go. Please point me in a right direction.
I need to have an info about method's name and structure's type this method is attached to when i have its pointer as interface{} in function argument.
Here is short example:
type MyStruct struct {
  SomeField int
}

func (ms *MyStruct) SomeMethod() int {
  return ms.SomeField
}

func GetStructMethodInfo(funcPointer interface{}) {
  // I need here reflection of MyStruct type (or at least it's name "MyStruct") and method name "SomeMethod".
  // I do not need struct instance here, just type of it is enough.
  // debugger in VSCode shows that he knows all this
  // how can I get this info (through reflection may be?)
}

func main() {
  ms := &MyStruct{} //pointer to struct

  GetStructMethodInfo(ms.SomeMethod) //passing pointer to struct method (attached to struct instance)
}

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!
UPD: found a possible clue!
func PrintInfo(funcPointer interface{}) string {
  fmt.Println(
    runtime.FuncForPC(reflect.ValueOf(funcPointer).Pointer()).Name(),
  )
}

This prints both struct type and method's name! So I suppose it is available in runtime somehow. runtime.FuncForPC(fn).Name() returns info concatenated and decorated. Still need a way to raw reflections of struct type and method name.

If I use step-by-step debugging in vscode debugger shows me method name and structure's type as tooltip for funcPointer. So I guess this information should be available through reflection somehow?

It's not possible in Go unless you want to use the reflection also before calling GetStructMethodInfo() so that it can extract necessary information. Can you explain why do you want to do that in the first place? Is it only for educational purposes?

It is a kind of experiment yet. Don't know if it will work as I want to. I'm trying to build a router("mux") based on struct methods rather then functions. This reflection thing I need to be able to build an URL-string by given method reference.

You can't get all the information from the method (you can still get the type), however you can get all the information by passing the struct instead of the fuinction pointer
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    SomeField int
}

func (ms *MyStruct) SomeMethod() int {
    return ms.SomeField
}

func GetStructMethodInfo(funcPointer interface{}) {
    funcType := reflect.TypeOf(funcPointer)
    fmt.Printf("Function type: %v\n", funcType)
}

func GetStructInfo(structPtr interface{}) {
    structType := reflect.TypeOf(structPtr)
    if structType.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        structType = structType.Elem()
    }

    fmt.Printf("Struct name: %s\n", structType.Name())

    method, found := reflect.TypeOf(structPtr).MethodByName("SomeMethod")
    if found {
        fmt.Printf("Method name: %s\n", method.Name)
        fmt.Printf("Method type: %v\n", method.Type)
    }
}

func main() {
    ms := &MyStruct{SomeField: 42}

    GetStructMethodInfo(ms.SomeMethod)

    GetStructInfo(ms)
}

This outputs the following:
Function type: func() int
Struct name: MyStruct
Method name: SomeMethod
Method type: func(*main.MyStruct) int


You looking for method by it's name and then printing this name. This is just the same as doing println("SomeMethod"). What I need is to "print" method's name without knowing it ahead. And structure's name as well.
